# Python pandas calculating average price within 15 minute time frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe that contains datetime and price.

Here is a sample chosen at random

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
          price           datetime
239035    5.05 2016-04-14 14:13:27
1771224   5.67 2016-08-30 14:19:47
2859140   4.00 2016-12-05 20:57:01
1311384   7.71 2016-07-08 18:16:22
141709    4.19 2016-04-07 13:30:00
2802527   3.94 2016-11-30 15:36:11
1411955   7.27 2016-07-20 13:55:20
2215987   4.87 2016-10-07 19:56:13
```

The datetime is accurate to the second.

I want to calculate the average price every 15 minutes starting at 9:00am and ending at 4:30pm, and store the new data into a new dataframe.

I could do it the old fashion way, make a list of all the 15 minute time intervals within 9am-4:30pm for each date, and iterate through each row of the CSV file, check its time and dump it into the appropriate bucket. Then find the average value for each bucket in each day.

But I was wondering if there is a nicer way to do this in panda. if not I'll just brute force my way through it...

Comment: Review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: I updated my question with how I would usually do it the "brute force way"... But I think there should be an easier way to accomplish what I want to do, since Pandas is a data analytics tool....

Comment: Can't read your data using `pd.read_clipboard()` which makes it harder. (read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)). Also, adding the desired output would be nice.

Comment: How about now? To test it, I just Ctrl-C the data right and run pd.clipboard() right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df2 = df.resample(rule='15Min', on='datetime').mean()
```

Then you filter out the times you don't want using boolean indexing. It's better to work with a `DateTimeIndex`:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('datetime', drop=False)
df2.between_time('9:00','16:30')
```

Comment: And I can pass in the start_time and end_time, so that it knows where to start and where to end?

Comment: Yes, for this the easiest would be to use `set_index('datetime')`then you can filter. I'll add that

Comment: Worked very well. That saved a lot of manual labor. Thanks again.

Comment: I also saw an option to resample only business days, removing all weekends and holidays.

df.resample('B')

is this correct?